# Scrollable div between fixed (top and bottom) divs

Tags: html, scroll, overflow

I am having trouble making the middle div not overflow to the next one. This is for a chat, the middle div would contain the messages and would be the only "scrollable" section.

The main chat layout is created as follows (inline CSS for better understanding):

```
<div id="divContainer" runat="server" style="box-sizing: border-box; word-wrap: break-word; width: 20%; max-height: 35%; position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0%; box-sizing: border-box;">
   <div id="divTop" style="float: left;width: 100%;"><span id="spanChatMinimize" style="float: right; padding: 3px;">_</span>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both"></div>
   <div id="divBody" runat="server" style="overflow-y: scroll; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
   <div id="divControls" runat="server" style="position:absolute;box-sizing: border-box; bottom:0px; width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Then i throw some programmatically-created divs (one for each chat comment, with no relevant style) to "divBody" and some programmatically-created controls to "divControls".

I can't make "divBody" stay between "divTop" and "divControls", being the only one with scroll, and i don't want fixed heights beside the container.

See the http://jsfiddle.net/r7scgxwf/2/

The scrollbar of the messages ("divBody") is there, but grey (inactive), as it seems to me that it overflows the "divControls" and also the whole chat container ("divContainer"). The controls are visible, and the messages are visible (overflowing) beneath the space between controls.

So my question is, how can i make the middle div end when the controls div starts, adding scroll if necessary? Also not using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some height to your containing div #divContainer, and then a height for the chat div #divBody.

```
#divContainer { height: 150px; }
#divBody { height: 100px; overflow:auto;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8matvxto/